New Package or Updation Post
Before comp.text.tex (CTT) has announced the Package updation and New Package release, but from February onwards, it was stopped. May I know, is the updation/new release details shifted to any other cites? Please let me know.

You can subscribe to an RSS feed or a mailing list on CTAN, see https://ctan.org/ctan-ann.

I still see announcements in ctt.

Are you viewing CTT via the google group? Google no longer supports this (since February)

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes, I viewed in Google group only, thanks

@Marijn Thanks a lot for your kind advise
